# sql query to fetch exchange rate by dividing the amount in the same table

Tags: oracle, plsql

Given a table sales, with item selled in two different currencies how to get the exchange in EUR

Sales Table:

| item | currency | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | USD | 1000 |
| A | EUR | 833.33 |
| B | JPY | 50 |
| B | EUR | 200 |
| C | EUR | 10 |
| C | CAD | 2 |

Desired table:

| item | currency | exchange | exchCurrenct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | USD | 1.2 | EUR |
| B | JPY | 0.25 | EUR |
| C | CAD | 0.2 | EUR |

for each item we devide the amount with the currency different then  EUR by the amount of the EUR currency

any idea how i can solve this ?

would be good if can handle the case where for the same item i don't have EUR currency (USD and CZK for example) and
in one of the previous rows i caluculated the exchange  for USD so can i figure out CZK to EUR?

Comment: please take a look at https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql and try to fullfill it

Comment: Use 2 copies of your table.

Comment: @Akina - how does two copies of the table help?

Comment: It would be better to store exchange rates for every business date in a separate table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT item, t1.currency, t1.amount / t2.amount exchange, t2.currency exch_currency
FROM sales t1
JOIN sales t2 USING (item)
WHERE t1.currency != 'EUR'
  AND t2.currency = 'EUR';
```

PS. `(item, currency)` must be unique. `currency = 'EUR'` must exist for each `item` (if not then it will absent in the output).

---

> is there a way to handle the cas of two different currencies: (CAD and USD) and before that we have already USD to EUR ===> can we get CAD to EUR (using pl/sql!)? - Alaa

You may handle any amount of currencies from any side by according condition in WHERE. If some currency is present in both lists then exclude self-exchange by additional condition.

For example,

```
SELECT item, t1.currency, t1.amount / t2.amount exchange, t2.currency exch_currency
FROM sales t1
JOIN sales t2 USING (item)
WHERE t1.currency IN ('USD', 'EUR', 'JPY') 
  AND t2.currency IN ('EUR', 'GBP', 'CAD') 
  AND t1.currency != t2.currency;
```

Comment: is there a way to handle the cas of two different currencies: (CAD and USD) and before that we have already USD to EUR ===> can we get CAD to EUR (using pl/sql!)?

Comment: @Alaa Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

@Alaa - Your given table only has what an item sold for (at *one* some unknown time), the currency of that particular sale, and the amount of that sale in that currency at that one time. It seems you are depending on trying to compare a one-time sale in one currency to a one-time (different time) sale of the same item in another currency.  That is not how to approach this.  You will need a separate table of currency exchange rates, and effective dates of that exchange rate.  And you will need your sales table to include date of sale, that can be compared to 'effective date' of the exchange table.

Off the top of my head, assuming that all exchanges are against Euros

```
SQL> create table exchange_rate (exch_currency varchar2(3) primary key,
  2                              exch_rate number(4,2),
  3                              exch_eff_dte date);

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> create table sales (item_id varchar2(10),
  2                      sale_date date,
  3                      sale_currency varchar2(3),
  4                      sale_amt number(8,2),
  5              constraint fk_curr_exch foreign key (sale_currency)
  6                references exchange_rate (exch_currency)
  7  );

Table created.
```